# Como colocar variavel php em link JS

Tags: php, javascript

Olá galera tudo bem? estou com problema de colocar variável PHP em link JS, o que preciso saber disso pois estou tentando fazer um u sistema de login no meu site... vêem a linha de código r conseguem uma suposta solução. Desde já agradeço!!!!!!!!

---

O meu problema é que tenho essa linha de comando no JavaScript que etá dentro do arquivo:

```
<?
$opts = uniqid(rand(), true);
echo "<script> window.location.assign('http://localhost/web/'" . $opts . '") </script>;
?>
```

porém essa linha de código simplesmente não ocorre nada... Como proceder?

Comment: Experimente `"<script> window.location.assign('http://localhost/web/$opts') </script>";` ou `"<script> window.location.assign(\"http://localhost/web/$opts\") </script>";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente o seguinte bloco:

```
<?
$opts = uniqid(rand(), true);
echo "<script> window.location.assign('http://localhost/web/" . $opts . "') </script>";
?>
```

Você não esta fechando a `"` após a tag `<script>`

Esta colocando `'` a mais, veja: `'http://localhost/web/'" . $opts . '"`

Assim, se o valor da variável for `page1` vai ser impresso:
`'http://localhost/web/'page1`

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!!